# Culinary Uses for Wheat Grass Sprouts

Tags: culinary-uses, vegan, wheat

Typically the only way I've found people consuming wheat grass sprouts is through juicing. Can this item be used in cooking, preferably as a main ingredient?

(Please keep in mind that I'm vegan.)

Comment: Welcome, Mat. Please note that recipe requests are off-topic here. I've edited this question to be in line with our [culinary uses question guidelines](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/culinary-uses/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to juice wheat grass and consume raw if you want to get any health benefits and nutrients out of the superfood. Smoothies, ice creams and other beverages are good places to start consuming wheat grass juice. Freezing any plant or animal food will cause the cells in the food to expand and burst so it is best to drink any fresh juice right away before oxidation takes place and to not freeze or keep left overs.